# jquery or php if X is greater than Y

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm making a website that displays a basic crud that shows Companyname, Stock, Minumum, Maximum.

I would like to display an alert or a message somewhere if the Stock is greater than the maximum. How could I go about doing this? Here is my display page code.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Minumum</th>
        <th>Maximum</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody> 
        <?php
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['companyname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['stock']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['minumum']; ?></td>         
                    <td><?php echo $row['maximum']; ?></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="update1.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Edit</a>&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete1.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why is this tagged with Javascript and CSS, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an additional message in the `Stock` column with an `if` statement.

```
<td><?php echo $row['stock']; ?></td>
```

with

```
<td><?php echo $row['stock']; if ($row['stock'] > $row['maximum']) { echo " > maximum"; } ?></td>
```